# Error: Cannot read property 'songs' of undefined - discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm relatively new to coding and am currently trying to make a simple music bot. One of the highly requested features is a 'Now Playing' embed that updates every 5 seconds. I tried implementing this with the help of someone else on Stack Overflow a few days ago, but I'm getting this error that I don't know how to fix as I have only been doing discord.js for a few months now. I'll show you the code that works and the code that doesn't, thanks for your help in advance!

```js
const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
if (!queue)
 return message.channel.send({
  embed: { color: 'ff0000', description: `Nothing's playing right now.` },
 });
const song = queue.songs[0];
const seek =
 (queue.connection.dispatcher.streamTime -
  queue.connection.dispatcher.pausedTime) /
 1000;
const left = song.duration - seek;

let nowPlaying = new MessageEmbed()
 .setTitle('Now playing:')
 .setDescription(`${song.title}`)
 .setColor('#ff0000')
 .setThumbnail('https://img.icons8.com/clouds/2x/play.png')
 .addField(
  '\u200b',
  new Date(seek * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8) +
   '[ ' +
   createBar(song.duration == 0 ? seek : song.duration, seek, 10)[0] +
   '] ' +
   (song.duration == 0
    ? ' ◉ LIVE'
    : new Date(song.duration * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)),
  false
 );

if (song.duration > 0)
 nowPlaying.setFooter(
  'Time Remaining: ' + new Date(left * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)
 );

message.channel.send(nowPlaying);
```

And then the code that has the error stated above:

```js
const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
if (!queue)
 return message.channel.send({
  embed: { color: 'ff0000', description: `Nothing's playing right now.` },
 });
const song = queue.songs[0];
const seek =
 (queue.connection.dispatcher.streamTime -
  queue.connection.dispatcher.pausedTime) /
 1000;
const left = song.duration - seek;

let nowPlaying = new MessageEmbed()
 .setDescription(`Now Playing:\n**${song.title}**`)
 .setColor('#ff0000')
 .addField(
  '\u200b',
  new Date(seek * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8) +
   ' **[** ' +
   createBar(song.duration == 0 ? seek : song.duration, seek, 10)[0] +
   ' **]** ' +
   (song.duration == 0
    ? ' ◉ LIVE'
    : new Date(song.duration * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)),
  false
 );

message.channel.send(nowPlaying).then((message) => {
 var countdown = song.duration;

 const interval = setInterval(() => {
  const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
  const song = queue.songs[0];
  const seek =
   (queue.connection.dispatcher.streamTime -
    queue.connection.dispatcher.pausedTime) /
   1000;
  const left = song.duration - seek;

  let nowPlayingTest = new MessageEmbed()
   .setDescription(`Now Playing:\n**${song.title}**`)
   .setColor('#ff0000')
   .addField(
    '\u200b',
    new Date(seek * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8) +
     ' **[** ' +
     createBar(song.duration == 0 ? seek : song.duration, seek, 10)[0] +
     ' **]** ' +
     (song.duration == 0
      ? ' ◉ LIVE'
      : new Date(song.duration * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)),
    false
   );

  if (countdown < 0) clearInterval(interval);

  message.edit(nowPlayingTest);
 }, 5000);
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: NOTE: I am using an error handler in my main script, and I also tried using it in a try{} statement. This is from a module.exports command file, just to let you know.

Comment: `queue` is undefined. The `message.client.queue` Collection/Map does not have an element with the key `message.guild.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `Cannot read property 'songs' of undefined` indicates that the variable before `.songs` is undefined. In this case, `queue` is undefined.

In the code that works, you handle it properly: you check if `queue` is not undefined before access its `.songs`.

```js
if (!queue) // handle if queue is undefined
  return message.channel.send({
    embed: { color: 'ff0000', description: `Nothing's playing right now.` },
  });
// queue is guaranteed to be not undefined here
const song = queue.songs[0];
```

However, in the code that caused error, you didn't handle it in the `setInterval` handler.

```js
/** in setInterval() **/
const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
// queue may be undefined!
const song = queue.songs[0]; // error occurs if queue is undefined!
```

To fix the error, all you need to do is to handle the undefined case like the code that works. For example:

```js
const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
if (!queue) return clearInterval(interval); // when queue is gone, stop editing the embed message
// queue is guaranteed to be not undefined here!
const song = queue.songs[0]; // OK!
```